# ASP.NET MVC 3 keep posted form data in form when there are binding errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

When a user posts a form to register, if ModelState is not valid, I would like to have the input form values placed back into the appropriate form fields so they do not have to fill out the entire form again. I could pass back the object to the view and then set the value field on each form input. Is this the only way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: This should happen automagically. Can you post your view and controller?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you HAD to use the html helpers for this to work. How can I add an Id to a html helper?        @Html.TextBox("username")

Comment: One of the overloads takes an anonymous type for html attributes. @Html.TextBox("username", new { id = "whatever" }) if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML helpers by default exhibit this behavior. How are you coding this? Html.TextBoxFor does this for example. The helpers use the posted values when you are in a post action and render a view without redirecting.

Comment: I was using just plain html, not the helper class. Once I changed to helpers, it worked fine. Thanks.